# when a process can't start in the beginning,supervisorctl update will hang

Tags: supervisord

In a case,when a process can't start in the beginning,eg the binary defined in the conf doesn't exist or conf error,the program can't start to running state,still stay in backoff state.

```
ex_sample_1.1.1.0.223817.486782  BACKOFF    can't find command '/home/admin/ex_sample_1.1.1.0.223817.486782/ex_sample'
```

then if we remove the supervisor conf,run sudo supervisorctl update,the command will hang forever。

I have read the supervisor code,but still have a little confused,maybe I stoll doesn't catch the point. when I input sudo supervisorctl update after I remove the BACKOFF program supervisor conf, supervisorctl will call stopPorcessGroup, send this rpc all to supervisord http server.

```
results = supervisor.stopProcessGroup(gname)
```

and it hang,why stopProcessGroup has no timeout? When the rpc all to supervisord service,supervisord service will call killall function,I thought it shoud be call once, if killall function failed,it will return to supervisorctl, why hang here?

```
killall = make_allfunc(processes, isRunning, self.stopProcess,
                               wait=wait)
killall.delay = 0.05
killall.rpcinterface = self
return killall # deferred
```

In the supervisord log, I found the killall function is called repeated, and no return to supervisorctl that the reason supervisorctl update hang, but I didn't find the code which call the killall function repeatedly. How and why is killall function called repeatedly, and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post the section of `supervisord.conf` that applies here? I was not able to reproduce your issue with a sample configuration.

Comment: it's bug,and been confirm:https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/746

Comment: I see, I tried with 3.2.3 where the issue was already fixed :)